# Extjs4, Control checkcolumn in grid renderer

Tags: extjs4

```
// Grid Column
{ header: "Defected", xtype: 'checkcolumn', dataIndex: "test", renderer : this.chTest}

// renderer function
chTest : function(value, metadata, record){
  if(record.get('A') == "Y"){
    return true; //I expected the checkbox be checked, but it show letter 'true'
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

How can I make the checkcolum be checked or unchecked in rederer function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.CheckColumn

I think you should define **test** field in model, not in render.